# AutoLayout: Two Stackviews have different right margins

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode9, uistackview

I have two similar StackViews both have trailing constraint of 8 to superview (same superview), but they look different and have different widths:

[image]

Constraints of Stack View #1 :
[image]

Constraints of Stack View #2 :
[image]

Comment: Are your stack views constrained relative to your root view's margin? Double click on stack view 2's trailing constraint and make sure that "constrains relative to margin" matches your other stack view's "constrains relative to margin"

Comment: Do both have the same alignment and distribution in the stack view configuration?

Comment: Give your labels background colors to confirm their frames. Is it possible your "cost" label has trailing spaces?